# 'create' button by calling update method instead of create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, request

here is my code to create new object via form:

my 'new.html.erb' file :

```
 <%= form_for @ticket, url: new_geradorqrcode_path(@ticket), html: { method: :put } do |t| %>
<p>
    <%= t.label :Descricao %></br>
    <%= t.text_area :descricao, cols: 20, rows: 5 %>

</p>

<p>
    <%= t.label :Tipo %></br>
    <%= t.text_field :tipo %>
</p>


<p>
    <%= t.label :Tamanho %></br>
    <%= t.number_field :tamanho_arquivo %>
</p>


 <p>
    <%= t.label :Cliente %></br>
    <%= t.text_field :cliente %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= t.label :Valor %></br>
    <%= t.number_field :valor %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= t.submit %>
</p>
```

but when i click in 'create' button, this error appears :

[erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JynfV.png)

I created both 'update ' and 'create' methods in controller :

```
def update
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
    ticket_params = params.require(:ticket).permit(:descricao,:valor, :cliente, :tamanho_arquivo, :tipo)
    @ticket.update(ticket_params)
    redirect_to url: geradorqrcode_path(@ticket), html: { method: :post }
end
```

and 'create' method :

```
def create
    @ticket = Ticket.new(params[:ticket])
    @ticket.save
    redirect_to url: geradorqrcode_path(@ticket), html: {method: :post}
end
```

My 'new' action

```
def new
    @ticket = Ticket.new

end
```

and 'routes.rb'

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

root 'geradorqrcode#index'
resources :geradorqrcode
end
```

Comment: can you add your `new` action? Or whatever action is rendering the form

Comment: It may be a routing issue, can we see your `config/routes.rb`? It's a hunch, but there's a possibility that you defined the `show` route ahead of the `new` one for the Ticket resource. Since order matters when defining routes, it can cause the problem you're seeing where it's trying to look for `id: "new"`.

Comment: Zoran, i add new updates in my question

Answer (score 0):

`<%= form_for @ticket, url: new_geradorqrcode_path(@ticket), html: { method: :put } do |t| %>`

This is your new form, which means you're dealing with a new object that hasn't been persisted to the database yet. The `html: { method: :put }` syntax is for when you want the form to update an object that has already been persisted. This would go on an edit page. In your case this is your `new` form which when submitted will go to your `create` action in the controller.

`<%= form_for @ticket, url: geradorqrcode_path(@ticket) do |t| %>`

This is how a new form should look. Try this and you should get what you're looking for. Another issue you'll run into is your `redirect_to` syntax. Remove the `html: { method: :post }` from both the `update` and `create` methods.

Comment: when i do`<%= form_for @ticket, url: new_geradorqrcode_path(@ticket), html: { method: :put } do |t| %>`  i get this error : `No route matches [POST] "/geradorqrcode/new"`

Comment: You need to remove the `html: { method: :put }` from your form as well as your controller `redirect_to` statements.

Comment: i do this, but error persists : 'No route matches [POST] "/geradorqrcode/new" '. when i put `html : {:method, :put}` application go to `update` method in controller, but when i remove , error message appears.

Comment: You're using the wrong route name for the form. You should be using the `geradorqrcode_path(@ticket)` route which is for the create action. Spend some time familiarizing yourself with rails routing, route names (`rake routes`), and what the different restful endpoints are.